# Total number of right-angled triangles that can be formed on an $n \times n$ chessboard

Tags: combinatorics, chessboard

I know that the total number of squares of any size on an $n \times n$ chessboard is equal to $ \frac 1 6 n(n + 1)(2n+1)$ (i.e. the sum of the first $n$ squares). But what is the general formula for the total number of right-angled triangles on an $n \times n$ chessboard? Thanks.

Comment: one way to possibly do this is to look at how for n=1, it's 4, n=2, it's 36, and find a pattern

Comment: Wild guess here, but each square contains $4$ right triangles that you can split it into. (Two when splitting by the major diagonal, two when splitting by the minor diagonal). I would hazard that it's your formula*4. Also, the formula that you provided is $\sum_{k=1}^n{k^2}$ Note that this would only be for Isosceles right triangles.

Comment: Do you want triangles with angles of 45 degrees, 45 degrees and 90 degrees? Or just any right-angled triangles?

Comment: oh, is this not talking about the lattice points?

Comment: You may get some hints here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2251616/chess-board-probability-problem/2251677

Comment: Yes, I know what the formula is. A condition is that the triangles must be formed by joining 3 vertices of the chessboard only.

Comment: Any three vertices? As in the corners of the board?

Comment: The number  of triangles would be the number of possible line segments, from vertex of one square to another vertex either above or to the right (but not both) times: $2n$ (either end of a line segment can be the location of the right angle in the triangle).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The number of rectangles that can be formed is clearly $\binom{n+1}{2}\binom{n+1}{2}$, since there are $\binom{n+1}{2}$ ways to choose the left and right sides and $\binom{n+1}{2}$ ways to choose top and bottom sides. For each such rectangle we have four right angled triangles. In this we are counting each triangle only once since we are counting them by the smallest rectangle that encloses them. Thus the number is $4\binom{n+1}{2}\binom{n+1}{2}$

Answer (score 0):

Each triangle contains one horizontal leg (which goes from left to right across chess board). The number of horizontal legs in one horizontal boundary (ie the horizontal boundary between squares or between squares and the edge of the board) is $\binom{n+1}{2}$. The number of horizontal boundaries in $n+1$. So there are $\binom{n+1}{2}(n+1)$ horizontal legs. Each horizontal leg can be in $2n$ triangles. So number of triangles is

$$\binom{n+1}{2}(n+1)2n \Rightarrow ((n+1)n)^2 \Rightarrow \left(2\binom{n+1}{2}\right)^2 $$.

For $n=1,2,3$ this gives $4, 36, 144$ triangles.